# Consuming variable lengths of data from a fixed length buffer in PHP

Tags: php, buffering, file-read

I have a file that's so large I'm unable to read it into a string in one go, but have to use buffering:

```
$fp = @fopen("bigfile", 'rb');
while (!feof($fp)) {
    //process buffer
}
```

For simplicity, say the file contains a sequence of integer string pairs, where the integer holds the length of the string. Then the code I want to realise in `process buffer`, is `unpack` an int, read that many characters from the buffer, then repeat.

I appreciate any suggestions in dealing with the scenario where the string spans one buffer to the next. I'm sure that this problem must have been solved and that there is a design pattern for it, I just don't know where to start looking.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: detect when you have a span, strip the "start chunk" off the end of the last block you read, and "prime" the var you're read from the file into with that chunk. e.g. `while($chunk .= fread(...)) { ...do stuff... if (have partial) { $chunk = get_last_partial(); } else { $chunk = ''; } }` That way you simply append the next chunk to whatever's left of the previous, eliminating the split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you're looking for an extra-clever solution, but straight forward would be:

```
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $len = fread($fp, 2); // integer-2 bytes ...?
    // <--- add checks here  len($len)==2 and so on...
    $len = unpack('S', $len); // pick the correct format character from http://docs.php.net/function.pack

    while(!feof($fp) && $len) {
        $cbRead = $len < MAX_CHUNK_LEN ? $len : MAX_CHUNK_LEN;
        $buf = fread($fp, $cbRead);
        // <--- add checks here  len($buf)==$cbRead and so on...
        $len -= $cbRead;
        // ... process buf 
    }
    if ( $len!=0 ) {
        errorHandler();
    }
    else {
        processEndOfString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect, really elegant solution, thank you. The key to your solution is the nesting of the while loops, which is what I hadn't thought of.  - One minor point that means you example code wont work is that the return type of unpack is an array, so you need something like the line $len = $len[1]